Проблема c Webview в Recyclerview
Возникла проблема с Webview, размещённом в Recyclerview.
Мобильное приложение простое. Чат, получаемый по API с сайта. Прилетает имя и время сообщения. Они вставляются в TextView.
И прилетает само сообщение в html формате с картинками. Оно вставляется в Webview.(на картинке - текст и смайлики на белом фоне)
И вот в Webview почти всё почему-то меняет пропорции. Т.е. текст то сжимается, то растягивается, то показывается нормальным.
Как починить? Как сделать так, чтобы текст был во всех сообщениях одного размера?
В чатадаптере делал так:
holder.webViewText.settings.useWideViewPort = true
holder.webViewText.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

Текст становится очень малого размера. Невозможно прочитать.
Добавляю это:
holder.webViewText.settings.textZoom = 300

Всё становится снова таким же как на скриншоте.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Размер текста и его пропорции (на белом фоне) должны быть одинаковыми.
А сейчас они совсем разные. Текст то сжат, то растянут.
Хочу узнать, как это исправить.
